# c++ wxwidgets nested frame

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

i have two frames , how can i put one frame in the other and not open it in a new window ?
something like tabs..

Comment: Have you looked at wxNotebook?  Search the web for wxFrameBuilder.

Comment: i could not find it , but what i need is something like to stick a frame in a panel..

Comment: Here's the wiki page: http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxNoteBook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be trying to 'stick a frame in a panel'!  Panels go inside frames, not the other way around.

As Thomas Matthews said, if you want tabs, use wxNoteBook